# Sharepoint Online default search result/scope in the small "global" search box

Tags: search, sharepoint-online, search-results, search-scope, office-365

We are using O365/SharePoint Online 2013.

Can the default search result/scope in the small/global search box in upper right corner of SharePoint sites be changed? As the default is "This Site" and we would like it to be "Everything".

I very much appreciate any help regarding this problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve the goal, you can go to configure search navigation.

Here are the steps for your reference:

1. Go to the Site settings page, click Search Settings under Search.
2. In the section of Configure Search Navigation, click Add Link to add the the following links:

   1). Title = Everything; URL = /search/pages/results.aspx

   2). Title = People; URL = /search/pages/peopleresults.aspx

   3). Title = Conversations; URL = /search/pages/conversationresults.aspx

   4). Title = This Site; URL =/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx
   Note: The top option will be the default.
3. Click OK.

Note: It's available for the site level, not the site collection level. That is, if you want to set this requirement on all sites in the site collection, it's required to set them one by one.

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/244788.aspx

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/0d0f69f8-b461-4bd1-896e-3ef8c06b8036/set-everything-as-a-default-scope-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Marked this as the answer because it's exactly what I asked for. Thank you. :)

Comment: Does this work on modern SharePoint online sites?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Go to Site settings > Site collection Administration > Search Settings on the site where you want to be able to search for everything. ( You have to do the following steps for every sitecollection. )

Set "**Search Center URL**" to your global search center url. ( url/sites/searchcenter/pages)

Uncheck "**Use the same results page settings as my parent**" and then click the radio button "**Send queries to a custom results page url**." ( url/sites/searchcenter/pages/results.aspx )

[image]

Comment: User19952 thank you very much for your answer. I marked the other answer as correct one because it is a direct answer to what I actually asked and as your method does not change the default scope that shows in the search box and the drop-down disappears. Still I wanted to mention that I tested your method too and it works also in redirecting the search so thank you. :)

Comment: I just wanna help so no worries. :)

Answer (score 1):

For people who have "modern pages", the default "search this site" cannot be changed. The default will be the O365 search experience, without being redirected to the search center, and without refiners.

[Reference](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Is-there-any-option-to-create-search-results-page-in-modern-team/td-p/271316)